# blackberry layout

Tags: blackberry

I need to port my app from iPhone to blackberry, but I'm new in blckberry.

In my app I have some buttons with labels under them. It seems I cant set any views by coordinates. I should use field manager (FM) insteed. So, in this case, I need to have vertical FM for button and it's label, some horizontal FM for buttons, and vertical FM for button's forizontal FMs
(PictureBackgroundButtonField - is a class from customButtonsDemo)

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm1 = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm2 = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm3 = new HorizontalFieldManager();

        VerticalFieldManager sho = new VerticalFieldManager();
        shopping = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Shoping.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        shopping.setChangeListener(this);
        sho.add(shopping);
        sho.add(new RichTextField("Shopping",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm1.add(sho);

        VerticalFieldManager din = new VerticalFieldManager();
        dining = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Dinning.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        dining.setChangeListener(this);
        din.add(dining);
        din.add(new RichTextField("Dining",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm1.add(din);

        VerticalFieldManager ent = new VerticalFieldManager();
        entertainment = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Entertainment.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        entertainment.setChangeListener(this);
        ent.add(entertainment);
        ent.add(new RichTextField("Entertainment",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm1.add(ent);

        VerticalFieldManager map = new VerticalFieldManager();
        maps = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Maps.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        maps.setChangeListener(this);
        map.add(maps);
        map.add(new RichTextField("Maps",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm2.add(map);

        VerticalFieldManager pro = new VerticalFieldManager();
        promotions = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Promotions.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        promotions.setChangeListener(this);
        pro.add(promotions);
        pro.add(new RichTextField("Promotions",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm2.add(pro);

        VerticalFieldManager par = new VerticalFieldManager();
        parking = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Parking.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        parking.setChangeListener(this);
        par.add(parking);
        par.add(new RichTextField("Parking",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm2.add(par);

        VerticalFieldManager wha = new VerticalFieldManager();
        whatson = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home WhatsOn.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        whatson.setChangeListener(this);
        wha.add(whatson);
        wha.add(new RichTextField("What's On",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm3.add(wha);

        VerticalFieldManager moe = new VerticalFieldManager();
        moeinfo = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home MOEinfo.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        moeinfo.setChangeListener(this);
        moe.add(moeinfo);
        moe.add(new RichTextField("MOE Info",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm3.add(moe);

        VerticalFieldManager fac = new VerticalFieldManager();
        facebook = new PictureBackgroundButtonField("HomePage/Home Facebook.png", Field.FOCUSABLE);
        facebook.setChangeListener(this);
        fac.add(facebook);
        fac.add(new RichTextField("Facebook",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
        hfm3.add(fac);

        vfm.add(hfm1);
        vfm.add(hfm2);
        vfm.add(hfm3);
        add(vfm);
```

But only first of my buttons shown in every hfm*. Where are athers?

Comment: 1 snap = 1000 words, so you should post the iOS app snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text fields use all horizontal space, so second button in horizontal field manager is outside the screen. In this case you need to sublass text field to make it's size custom, or use something else.

Comment: Is this an answer or udpate for the question?

Comment: Answer. Any other solutions are wellcome.